# Numerical solution to Differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerics

I want to get the differential solution numerically. I used wolfram alpha. here  is the [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27%5Br%5D+%2B+1%2Fr+*x%27%5Br%5D+-+0.5%2F%28r%5E2%29*Sin%5B2+x%5Br%5D%5D+%2B+2%2Fr*Sin%5Bx%5Br%5D%5D%5E2+-+++0.2+Sin%5Bx%5Br%5D%5D+-+Sin%5B2*x%5Br%5D%5D+%3D%3D+0%2C+x%5B0.00001%5D+%3D%3D+Pi%2Cx%27%280.00001%29%3D%3D-1.10247294987308759).

I tried this code on the Mathematica file.

```
sols4 = NDSolve[{x''[
       r] + (1/r) x'[r] - (0.5/r^2) Sin[2 x[r]] + (2/r) Sin[x[r]]^2 - 
      0.2 Sin[x[r]] - Sin[2 x[r]] == 0, x[0.00001] == Pi, 
    x'[0.00001] == -1.1024724270140055}, x[r], {r, 0.00001, 100}, 
   Method -> "BDF"];
Plot[Evaluate[x[r] /. sols4], {r, 0.00001, 100}]
```

It makes me able to get the solution. But I also need a parametric plot as mentioned in wolfram alpha. How I can have that plot? Additionally, as I am using a shooting method and I need a solution to be zero at infinity. Can anyone tell me how I can avoid oscillation at large distances?

Thanks.

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{x[r] /. First@sols4, D[x[r] /. First@sols4, r]} // 
  Evaluate, {r, 0.00001, 100}]`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Do you have any idea that how I can get rid of oscillation at r>20? I need solution to be zero as like it is before r=20.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. The solution is the solution. Are you talking about modifying your model so that it does that or defining a new function that is the solution above until $r=20$ and then zero afterward? (And what do you mean by zero? Do you mean it's at the origin after that or that the vertical component is zero?)

Comment: Actually, my differential equation is a boundary value problem. With x[0.0001]=Pi and x[infinity]=0. So I used the shooting method and converted it into an initial value problem with x[0.0001]=Pi and x'[0.0001]=-(some guessed value). But my gussed value gives oscillation at large distance. But I need x[infinity]=0 not oscillation.

Comment: You are changing the question.  Please open a new question that includes both the code above and the boundary condition at large `r` that you are trying to match.  My guess is that you are trying to match a separatrix at large `r', which typically is difficult but possible numerically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sols4 = NDSolveValue[{x''[
       r] + (1/r) x'[r] - (0.5/r^2) Sin[2 x[r]] + (2/r) Sin[x[r]]^2 - 
      0.2 Sin[x[r]] - Sin[2 x[r]] == 0, x[0.00001] == Pi, 
    x'[0.00001] == -1.1024724270140055}, x, {r, 0.00001, 100}, 
   Method -> "BDF"];

Plot[sols4[r], {r, 0.00001, 100}]
```

[image]

For a parametric plot use [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
ParametricPlot[
 {sols4[r], sols4'[r]}, {r, 0.00001, 100}]
```

[image]